# Seeing different 'Button' codes from tutorials in VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I am trying to insert data to SQL server table with using C# ASP.NET. I watched a lot of tutorial video. If I create a button and double click on it, I see quite different codes from videos and other tutorials.
To make clear my problem, I added my and tutorials' code screenshots.

What shoud be the reason and how can I fix it?

This is from tutorials:

[image]

This is from my VS 2013

[image]

Comment: Your project is set to use VB instead of C#.

Comment: @Jasen How can I change it

Comment: Start over and use the C# template instead of the VB template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a Visual Basic template to create your project. Notice the source file in your screenshot is *Default.aspx.vb*. You'll need to create the project using the C# template.

[image]

**Edit:** I changed the screenshot to  *New Web Site* instead of *New Project*.